# Should we rename this tag to [improve] its usage?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, retag-request

The [improve](/questions/tagged/improve) tag (33 questions) has a clear excerpt explaining its intended usage:

> For questions about the Improve Edit button that lets you perform further editing to a pending suggested edit. For the 'Improve this question/answer' link you see when you're not logged in to suggest an edit, please use [suggested-edits].

It's used properly on most of its questions. But on a significant minority, it's used as a meta tag, talking about the general concept of improvement: [Should I improve questions that are not mine by adding information?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340509/) or [Helping users figure out where to post their question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262114/), for example. The tag's vague name seems to make it a magnet for this kind of bad usage.

Beyond simply editing [improve](/questions/tagged/improve) out of the questions where it's used in a way inconsistent with its excerpt, should it be [renamed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/) to discourage bad usage? Or is there another step which may be taken to similarly discourage incorrect usage?

Personally, I would prefer renaming it to [improve-edit](/questions/tagged/improve-edit) by Magical Moderator Powers<sup>TM</sup> after all the meta-tag uses are removed.

Comment: @Ollie personally, I'd prefer [improve-edit], just because often the tag is used for the process in general and not the button itself.

Comment: The button used to be just called "Improve" rather than "Improve Edit", hence the name of the tag.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Did it?  I can see how that would make sense... like a Delete Question button paired with a [delete] tag...

Comment: The button currently says "Improve Edit", so I don't see why we shouldn't rename it to `[improve-edit]`. Yes, renaming makes perfect sense to me in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the cleanup; I've 'renamed' the tag. When I say 'rename', I actually meant I

- created the [improve-edit](/questions/tagged/improve-edit) tag by editing a question
- copied over the existing tag excerpt and wiki
- suggested [improve](/questions/tagged/improve) as a synonym of [improve-edit](/questions/tagged/improve-edit)
- approved the synonym
- merged [improve](/questions/tagged/improve) into [improve-edit](/questions/tagged/improve-edit)

Note to self: I should write a userscript for this ...

Comment: Considering that this button only exist when reviewing suggested edits, why not merging into suggested edits tag?

Comment: @Braiam that tag has 2,500+ questions, sometimes it helps having a slightly-narrower-but-still-quite-common subtag. Whether this is one of those cases is open to (a new) discussion; here I'm merely carrying out the decision of the community (+12/-2 on the question, IMHO that's a decisive majority).

Comment: @Braiam to give you an idea why a tag like this is useful; suppose I find a bug related to the [tag:improve-edit] functionality. It's easier to check existing questions tagged [tag:improve-edit] rather than filtering [tag:suggested-edits] with "improve edit" which may be less effective for various reasons; SE search is less predictable than I wish it was.

Comment: The thing is that the team keeps saying that they monitor _all bugs_, so having a separated tag for _bugs_ wouldn't benefit the team, hence your argument doesn't hold water. And even then, there's only two questions that use the tag without using suggested-edits out of the measly 26 that this tag has and both are about something else that is not specific to the button: the in page popup editor that appears when you try to review a suggested edit from the post route and the other about an error message.

Comment: In other words, there's no reason to have a separated tag because the tag seems to be unable to exist without the presence of the greater topic tag anyways (which itself is pretty small). Tags are supposed to cover the topic of a book, all those questions with all their answers and comment don't even reach a chapter.

Comment: Sure, I'm not preventing you from opening a new discussion to merge this tag (and probably some others as well?) into [tag:suggested-edits]. It might break my workflow but I'm just a single user ... not that important.